# What would cause a bluetooth device to show up on a smart phone, but not on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, game-controller

I have an Xbox Series X controller that uses Bluetooth that I'm trying to use on my PC running Windows 10. I have a no-name Bluetooth radio that I'm using as my receiver, with a driver that's just called "Generic Bluetooth Radio". The two mobile phones in this situation are a Samsung Galaxy S7, and a Samsung Galaxy S9.

Bluetooth settings on my PC are not detecting the controller when I use the "add device" wizard, and I am going through the pair procedure on the controller. Strangely enough, if I use my phone to detect new Bluetooth devices, the controller shows up! Even more strange is that my PC will detect my phone, so I know the receiver is working.

This procedure was tried using a different phone, and the configuration was also moved to another different Windows 10 PC, but the results remained consistent: The phone can detect the PC and controller, but the PC can only see the phone.

What could be causing the controller to be detected by the phones, but not by the PCs?

Comment: Can Xbox Series X controllers be plugged in via USB? I just might forego collecting Xbox360 controllers... :P

Comment: @Casey Yeah I can get the controller to work wired no problem. I tested it using the Xbox Accessories app. I just want to get this working wirelessly because my USB cables are very short.

Comment: Please kindly check if this can resolve your problem: [Fix Bluetooth problems in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-bluetooth-problems-in-windows-10-723e092f-03fa-858b-5c80-131ec3fba75c)

Comment: Thanks @Sunny, I appreciate the help. I've gone through those troubleshooting steps and they haven't made a difference.